# Thunderbird and google mail

Tags: thunderbird, mail, google

I haven't used Thunderbird for a while but when I started to use it again I found out that I have to give the application the password for imap.google.com. As far as I know, it's the same password as the email's. After I typed the password, I have an error that "login failed".

What should I do?

I'm using ubuntu for a couple of months and I don't know it very well yet!

Thanks for helping! :D

Answer (score 0):

https://security.google.com/settings/security at the bottom of the page generate a password for thunderbird.

Comment: This is in case that you are using a 2-step verification in Google Accounts.

Comment: It can be, then allow imap in https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/fwdandpop and click save settings